# Laptop doesn't start because libudevso.0

Tags: boot

Hello I have the following error when I turn on my computer.

```
mountall: error while loading shared libraries: libudev.so.0 : cannot open shared object file: Error 40'
```

As I think I've read on the internet this can be solved by doing this

```
sudo mount -o remount, rw /

ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.0
```

But when I do that the systems says
    Too many levels of symbolic links

Anyone has a solution to this that doesn't involve reinstalling elementary OS? I don't want to lose all the data that I have on my `/home` folder